# GulpJS, ошибка SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Есть приложение, внутри него инициализируются задачи gulp, из-за того что приложение запускается в строгом режиме, нода бросает ошибку `SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.`

Я так понял что это из-за того в gulp'e используется устаревшая версия `graceful-fs`. Я пробовал поставить `gulp 4` но не помогло, появились другие ошибки. Тогда я порылся, и нашел где ошибка в файле `\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\gaze\node_modules\globule\node_modules\glob\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:80` нужно исправить в строке `open(req.path, req.flags || "r", req.mode || 0777, req.cb)` значение `0777` на `0o777`, тогда все работает. Но это как-бы не вариант, я же не буду говорить всем кто использует мое приложение о том что нужно фиксить `gulp`.

**Кто знает** как избежать данной проблемы с запуском в строгом режиме?

Comment: А можно минимальный пример для воспроизведения? А то как-то у всех галп нормально работает...

Comment: @Qwertiy, Запускаю express 4, в стартовом файле напишите `const gulp = require('gulp');` запустите его с параметром `use_strict`. Этого достаточно для воспроизведения бага.